# Good Mathematica package for computing Feynman graphs (resource request)?

Tags: physics

I came over from the physics stackexchange to ask the following: I was wondering if anyone had any go-to Mathematica packages for computing higher-order Feynman graphs. Specifically ones that would allow me to construct higher spin fields like $h_{\mu\nu}$ and then be able to write the rules in myself (I have the Feynman rules derived, I just need a nice package that understands what I am typing).

I have only ever worked with diffgeo.m before, so if that could be used alongside a Feynman graph package that would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: FeynCalc (to calculate amplitudes) and FeynArts (to generate graphs) are probably your best bet. Google for those names, and you'll get the site(s) for download.